# Can the senate vote to condemn? Is this even an official practice?

Tags: united-states, senate, house-of-representatives

Recently, the House voted to condemn 3 of the President's tweets. This gave me two questions:

1. Can the Senate do the same
2. Is "condemning" an official practice that has been used before? Is it written down in some statute?

Comment: I don't understand why people downvoted this question. Condemning actions is a standard political process in US congress and many other legislatures which deserves to be explained.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Yes, either chamber can pass a resolution.  These resolutions have no legal effect.  The only thing that they could do is bind that chamber with a new legislative rule.  But in general, they don't do that.  They're much closer to signing a petition.
2. No.  All this is is taking a vote under the rules of the chamber.  It's not an official practice, nor is it mentioned in a statute.

Some Republican examples:

- [Condemning anti-semitism](https://zeldin.house.gov/media-center/press-releases/reps-zeldin-stefanik-budd-introducing-resolution-today-condemning-anti).
- [Condemning Modern Monetary Theory](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/116/sres182):

  > #### S.Res. 182 is a simple resolution in the United States Congress.
  >
  > A simple resolution is used for matters that affect just one chamber of Congress, often to change the rules of the chamber to set the manner of debate for a related bill. It must be agreed to in the chamber in which it was introduced. It is not voted on in the other chamber and does not have the force of law.

Answer (score 5):

**Simply put, Resolutions are what Congress *does*.**

Some resolutions are to enact new legislation.  Some resolutions are to assign reps to internal committees.  Some resolutions are purely symbolic.  Some are done as harmless gifts to constituents.

The resolution to "Condemn 3 of President Trump's Tweets" that you describe falls into the "Purely Symbolic" category.  It is simply the House making an official statement that they don't like what Trump said.  And nothing more.

To give an idea of how Resolutions are used in the House, here are the 10 most recently introduced (not accepted, debated or voted on, just introduced) resolutions at this time:

- H.Res 538 Recognizing the historical, cultural, and religious significance of Sikh Americans, and for other purposes.
- H. Res 537 Expressing the sense of the House of Representatives regarding United States policy recognizing the Assyrian Genocide.
- H. Res 536 Strongly condemning the violent actions of Antifa and recognizing that it engages in domestic terrorism.
- H. Res 535 Recognizing August 6, National Night Out, the national coming together of Americans all over the Nation to unite and promote public safety.
- H. Res 534 Recognizing the 60th anniversary of the U.S. Open of Surfing.
- H. Res 533 Recognizing the accomplishments of professional surfer and surfwear executive Danny Kwock
- H. Res 532 Proposing a strategy to make Medicare available to all Americans.
- H. Res 531 Expressing concern over the prevalence of hazardous working conditions for children, especially the worst forms of child labor in the mining of cobalt and other minerals in the Democratic Republic of the Congo.
- H. Res 530 Expressing the sense of the House of Representatives that the amount of the Members' Representational Allowance should be increased in response to increasing threats against Members of the House.
- H. Res 529 Honoring the life of Petty Officer Raul Guerra of Montebello, California, who perished on October 8, 1967, during military operations off northern Vietnam, and the work of the Bring Raul Home Committee to have Petty Officer Raul Guerra's remains laid to rest in California.

Comment: That list is a really good example of just how all over the place resolutions can be.